# How to load .css file from parent directory with .htaccess rule?

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two rules in my `.htaccess` file.
First is to hide extensionas of all files in `parent`, and second is for removing `.php` values and file `id` and also to "create" and display that URL in subfolder `subfolder`. The problem is that files in `subfolder` can't load `.css` and `.js` files since they are in `parent/css` and `parent/js` folder. I get: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".
Can't find any rule to change path or maybe exclude that `css/js` files.

This is my folder structure:

```
/parent/
|__ .htaccess
|__ index.php
|__ about.php
|__ details.php
|__ CSS
|  |__style.css
|__ JS
|  |__script.js
```

Theese are my rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^subfolder/([^/]+)$ /parent/details.php?value=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule are the top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!parent/)[^/]+/((?:CSS|JS)/.+)$ /parent/$1 [L,NC,R]
```